# Download Excel file using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Hi i want to download XLX file using spring mvc ajax call.Below is my ajax call to server.

```
 $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'downloadExcel',
    beforeSend : function() {
        startPreloader();
    },
     complete: function(){
         stopPreloader();
     },
    success : function(response){
        console.log(response);
            var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = downloadUrl;
            a.download = "downloadFile.xlsx";
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
    }
});
```

Here is my server code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<LicenceType> downloadExcel() {
        return licenceTypeService.findAllLicenceType();
    }
```

My code actually download the excel file, but on the excel sheet it showing like
`[Object][Object]`

Comment: Why use ajax at all? why not have `<a href="downloadExcel" download="downloadFile.xlsx">Download</a>`

Comment: i need it in ajax way.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been almost a year but it worked for me with this:

```
var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel' });
```

Answer (score 0):

`<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>`

```
    $("#Xcel").click(function () {
        $("#Tab").table2excel({
            exclude: '.exclude',
            filename: 'MatchedSDNListNames.xls'
        });
    })
```

Can be a good choice if you are looking to import table as excel.